# Performance of inserting rows with a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I optimize the below query. You can see the only difference is with the Amount column.

```
INSERT INTO TableA
( Name, Amount, Cityname)

(SELECT Name,(Expense *15),CityName
FROM TableB B JOIN TableC C ON B.Id = C.FID AND B.Number = E23)
UNION
(SELECT Name,(Expense *25),CityName
FROM TableB B JOIN TableC C ON B.Id = C.FID AND B.Number = E23)
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: perhaps provide details of the issues with it. why doesn't this perform well for example? otherwise this is just a code review

Comment: There are more unions like this . i just added 2 to make it smaller

Comment: why don't You do multiple inserts?

Comment: Why UNION? You can use UNION ALL as it will be obviously different in amount

Comment: Yes, you could prepopulate the table with the data you need to avoid having to generate it this way.

Comment: Which tables do `name`, `expense` and `cityname` reside in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
INSERT INTO TableA ( Name, Amount, Cityname)
    SELECT Name, (Expense * v.val), CityName
    FROM TableB B JOIN
         TableC C
         ON B.Id = C.FID AND B.Number = E23 CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES (15), (25)) c(val);
```

This is not exactly the same, because it does not reduce duplicates.  But, I doubt that you really want to do that.

Then, you want indexes on `TableB(Number, ID)` and `TableC(FID)`.

Comment: @Happy why does this need a cursor?

Comment: @Tanner because then query wont be too long?

Comment: @Happy . . . Using a cursor is generally a bad idea.  Use a cursor to improve performance is like walking backwards to get somewhere faster.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can do.

1. Covering Indexes.  Index TableB on Id,Number.   Index TableC on FID.
2. UNION ALL.  If you aren't expecting any duplicate data that needs to be eliminated, then UNION ALL performs faster than UNION, since it won't do the extra work of checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(255)
,@Expense1 INT
,@Expense2 INT
,@CityName VARCHAR(255)

SELECT @Name = [Name]
    ,@Expense1 = (Expense * 15)
    ,@Expense2 = (Expense * 15)
    ,@CityName = CityName
FROM TableB B
JOIN TableC C ON B.Id = C.FID
    AND B.Number = E23

INSERT INTO TableA (
    NAME
    ,Amount
    ,Cityname
)
VALUES (
    @Name
    ,@Expense1
    ,@CityName
)
,(
    @Name
   ,@Expense2
    ,@CityName
 )
```

---

And also you should consider the two points mentioned by @TabAlleman in the answer. I'm just repeating here what he said --

1. Covering Indexes. 
   Index TableB on Id, Number. 
   Index TableC on FID.
2. UNION ALL. 
   If you aren't expecting any duplicate data that needs to be eliminated, then UNION ALL performs faster than UNION, since it won't do the extra work of checking for duplicates.

Comment: what is advantage of using this type of query?